# Bind sortable index value to a knockout viewmodule

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

I have a json structure that looks like the following, where "**Position**" is a sort value.

```
 [
  {"ID":1, "Title":"Title 1", "Position":1},
  {"ID":2, "Title":"Title 2", "Position":2},
  {"ID":5, "Title":"Title 3", "Position":3},
  {"ID":7, "Title":"Title 4", "Position":99}
];
```

**knockout-sortable** uses an **index** to sort sortable items

Is there a way to bind this sortable index value to my Position property?

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgpbX/) of my code.

Basically, when an item is dragged to a new position, I want to update the viewmodule so that I can save the change back to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, I like to add a subscription to my observableArray that takes one pass through the array and properly sets the "index".

Here is an extension that would work for your use case:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.withIndex = function(prop, startIndex, lastIndex) {
    //by default use an "index" observable
    prop = prop || "index";

    //whenever the array changes, make a single pass through to update the indexes
    this.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        var item;
        for (var i = 0, j = newValue.length; i < j; i++) {
            //create the observable if it does not exist
            item = newValue[i];

            if (!item[prop]) {
                item[prop] = ko.observable();
            }

            //special logic for the last one 
            item[prop]((lastIndex && i === (j - 1)) ? lastIndex : startIndex + i);   

        }
    }, this);

    return this;
};
```

You would use it like:

```
myObservableArray.withIndex("Position", 1, 99);
```

Here is your updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HVNUr/

Comment: This is beautiful! It does exactly what it's supposed to do and does it the "knockout" way.

Comment: Here is a slightly **updated** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVNUr/3/) that also includes a fix for the isDirty issue.

Answer (score 0):

I added an id on list container so I can "listen" dom modification that alter it.
I wrap the update position process in timer because the dom modification event was fired too much times.

```
var positions = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.Items(), function (item) {
    return item.Position();
});
positions.sort();
var itmer = null;

$('#container').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function () {
    if (itmer) clearTimeout(itmer);

    itmer = setTimeout(function () {
        var items = viewModel.Items();
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(items, function (item) {
            var index = $('#container [id=' + item.ID() + ']').last().index();
            var newPosition = positions[index];
            item.Position(newPosition);
        });
    }, 50);

});
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgpbX/1/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have to admit, you managed to get this working in ways I didn't think of. However, RP Niemeyer's answer below feels cleaner and will work across all browsers.